# How to extract duration of experience from resume using Python

Tags: python, regex

I have written logic to extract dates of experiences from the resume.
I have extracted experiences that have this format :

01/2017 - 04/2022

01/07/2017 - 31/07/2017

March 2017 - July 2022

Here is the code :

```
cur_datespan = None
    next_first_date = None
    delimeter_count = 0

    for ptoken, token in zip(tokens, tokens[1:]):
        token = str(token).lower().strip()
        ptoken = str(ptoken).lower().strip()
        tokenpair = token + " " + ptoken
        # find datespanes
        if re.search("\d+", token) != None:
            dates = search_dates(tokenpair, settings={
                                 'REQUIRE_PARTS': ['month', 'year']}) or []

        
        else:
            dates = []
        for date in dates:
            if next_first_date == None:
                next_first_date = date[1]
                delimeter_count = 0
            elif delimeter_count < 6:
                cur_datespan = (next_first_date, date[1])
                next_first_date = None
            else:
                next_first_date = date[1]
                delimeter_count = 0
        if delimeter_count > 50:
            next_first_date = None
            cur_datespan = None
        delimeter_count += len(token.split(" "))
        # find skill and add to dict with associated datespan
        if token.lower() in skills:
            skillset[cur_datespan].add(token)
        elif (ptoken + " " + token).lower() in skills:
            skillset[cur_datespan].add((ptoken + " " + token).lower())

    skilldict = {}
    for datespan, skills in skillset.items():
        for skill in skills:
            if skill not in skilldict:
                skilldict[skill] = []
            if datespan != None and datespan[1].month - datespan[0].month > 0:
                skilldict[skill].append(datespan)

    return skilldict
```

But I couldn't extract the experiences that have these formats for example :

March-July 2020

March 2020 - Current/Present

01/07/2017-31/07/2017 (date format "day_first")

2020-2021

From/Since 2020

From March 2020 to July 2022

Comment: for every format you may have to write separated regex. And later run all of them to see which one will give some results.

Comment: Look at `dateutil` which has a very accommodating parser that covers most of your difficult cases already.

Comment: Hey @Jan, I do like this problem and I may have crafted a reasonable regex to match your dates at once, though before sharing it, I'd like to understand if it's something that can be crossed with your code or is just useless as it is. Can you share what's your input, input type and what's the output you expect?

Comment: Hey @lemon, I have resumes that have skills with its experiences, i would like to extract skills with its experiences. For the basic dates [(Jun 2016 - Sep 2019),(01/07/2017-31/07/2017),(01/2017 - 04/2022),(04 Jan 2016 - Today)], I can do it.
But for the formats mentioned, thats not working.
The output expected is : 
{
"skillname": "react",
"experience": [
{
"from": "2017-01-15T00:00Z[GMT]",
"to": "2020-08-15T00:00Z[GMT]",
"duration": "P3Y7M"
}
]
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use re.findall as follows

```py
import re
resumes = ['01/2017 - 04/2022',
'01/07/2017 - 31/07/2017',
'March 2017 - July 2022',
'March-July 2020',
'March 2020 - Current/Present',
'01/07/2017-31/07/2017',
'2020-2021',
'From/Since 2020',
'From March 2020 to July 2022]']
pattern = r'(((Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)|(\d{1,2}\/){0,2})[- ]?\d{4}?)'

for resume in resumes:
    res = re.findall(pattern,resume)
    if len(res) > 1:
      print('from',res[0][0],'to',res[1][0])
    else:
```

output

```
from 01/2017 to 04/2022
from 01/07/2017 to 31/07/2017
from March 2017 to July 2022
-> March-July 2020
-> March 2020 - Current/Present
from 01/07/2017 to 31/07/2017
from 2020 to -2021
-> From/Since 2020
from March 2020 to July 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

import datefinder

import re

pattern = r'(\d{1,2}\s?\d{4})|(\d{4}\s?\d{1,2})|(\d{4})'

```
# Find all matches in the text
```

matches = re.findall(pattern, text)

```
# Extract the matched durations
```

durations = []
for match in matches:
for group in match:
if group:
durations.append(group)

print(durations)

## Initialize an empty list to store extracted month and year values

extracted_dates = []

## Iterate over the elements in the data list

for item in durations:
matches = datefinder.find_dates(item)

```
# Check if any matches were found
for match in matches:
    # Extract the month and year from the match
    month = match.month
    year = match.year
    
    # Append the extracted month and year to the extracted_dates list
    extracted_dates.append((month, year))
```

## Get unique years from the extracted_dates list

unique_years = set(year for month, year in extracted_dates)

## Print the extracted month and year values for each unique year

for year in unique_years:
has_month = False
for month, y in extracted_dates:
if y == year:
has_month = True
print(f"Year: {year}, Month: {month if month else '-'}")
if not has_month:
print(f"Year: {year}, Month: -")

output:

Year: 2017, Month: 2

Year: 2019, Month: 4

Year: 2019, Month: 4

Year: 2021, Month: 3

Year: 2021, Month: 2

Year: 2022, Month: 7

Year: 2022, Month: 6

Year: 2013, Month: 12